# IBM Toolchain and Continuous Delivery Plan issue regarding regions

Tags: ibm-cloud, toolchain

I am part of an organization on IBM Cloud (Bluemix) with several regions. I know we pay for the Continuous Delivery service in the US South region (Professional Plan) of our organization and from the usage page there is no distinction between regions, just organizations. However, when I switch to the UK region I get an error stating I have to upgrade the service from the Lite plan in order to use it. This is blocking us from using the Continuous Delivery within this region and we are unable to deploy our apps here at the moment.

[image: Error]

Is this correct or is this a bug with our account? Does the service need to be upgraded per region now? The service is incredible expensive as it is, so I would like to avoid doing this if it will double the cost....

Regards,

Kjetil

Comment: This seems like an account question. How about opening a ticket with IBM support?

Comment: You are probably right and I would open a ticket with IBM support if I could, but personally I do not have the rights to do so. I will track down the person who does. In the meanwhile, I was just as much asking if this scenario I am describing is actually the way the service is supposed to work? If it is, I guess I would have to follow your tip in the answer below. If it is not, I will raise a ticket with IBM Support.

Answer (score 2):

The [Continuous Delivery (CD) service](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ContinuousDelivery/index.html#cd_getting_started) is offered in multiple regions. A service instance can deploy to all IBM Cloud Public regions. Thus, if you use the CD service in US South, you can still deploy to Germany or UK. Or, if you use the CD service in Germany, you could still deploy to US East or US South.